# Asterisk Call Manager hangup event on Python

Tags: python, asterisk

How to hangup the recent originated call through AMI.? I used the code below to originate the calls but I don't know how am I supposed to hangup the same originated call.

```
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 5038

p = '''Action: login
Events: off
Username: %(username)s
Secret: %(password)s

Action: originate
Channel: Mobile/g1/%(phone_to_dial)s
WaitTime: 30
Timeout: 5
Exten: %(phone_to_dial)s
Context: home
Priority: 1



Action: Logoff
'''
def click_to_call(phone_to_dial, username, password, local_user):
    pattern = p % {
        'phone_to_dial': phone_to_dial,
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'local_user': local_user}
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((HOST,PORT))

    data = s.recv(1024)
    for l in pattern.split('\n'):
        print 'sending>>',1
        s.send(l+'\r\n')
        if l == "":
            data = s.recv(1024)
            print data
    data = s.recv(1024)
    s.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    click_to_call('918800726989',username='600',password='yourpass',local_user='11111')
```

I tried adding `Action: hangup` but it didn't seem to work. Any help please.?

**UPDATE:** Codes & Error I got after adding the actions, status and hangup:

```
import socket

HOST = '192.168.1.3'
PORT = 5038

p = '''Action: Login
Events: off
Username: %(username)s
Secret: %(password)s
ActionID: 1

Action: Originate
ActionID: 2
Channel: SIP/11111
Exten: %(phone_to_dial)s
Context: home
priority: 1

Action: Status
ActionID: 3
Channel: SIP/11111

Action: Hangup
ActionID: 4
Channel: SIP/11111

Action: Logoff
ActionID: 5

'''
def click_to_call(phone_to_dial, username, password, local_user):
    pattern = p % {
        'phone_to_dial': phone_to_dial,
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'local_user': local_user}
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((HOST,PORT))

    data = s.recv(1024)
    for l in pattern.split('\n'):
        s.send(l+'\r\n')
        if l == "":
            data = s.recv(1024)
            print data
    data = s.recv(1024)

    s.close()



if __name__=='__main__':
    click_to_call('55555',username='600',password='yourpass',local_user='11111')
```

Message I got after running the above code:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Response: Success


ActionID: 1

Message: Authentication accepted




Response: Success


ActionID: 2

Message: Originate successfully queued



Response: Error

ActionID: 3

Message: No such channel




Response: Error

ActionID: 4

Message: No such channel




Response: Goodbye


>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

1) listen events and see channel id for new created channel

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/asterisk+manager+events

2) put Hangup action(NOT event) with channel name

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Hangup

Comment: I did the same sir. But no success.! I used `Hangup` as an action. Please tell me what is wrong with my script. The objective for writing the program is to originate a call, get its status and hangup but I am lost somewhere and I don't seem to get the way out. Please help..!!

Comment: your script have no event listener nor hangup action

Comment: Do you care to explain a bit,please. I am new to asterisk.. I didn't get much tutorial on it. I added hangup action with my script but had no luck.. I also tried doing the things as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306115/how-to-get-the-status-of-an-asterisk-server-using-a-socket-python) but no help with it either.

Comment: There are nothing to explain. You just need do program. I not see how you added hangup action. Hangup action not in listing you provided,it REQUIRE channel name. I not see any attempt get that channel name. So sorry, you are never tried do that or not give us enought info to see your effort.

Comment: I updated the question with what I did lately. Can't still figure out where did I mistake. I included the suggestion you gave, still can't hangup the call. I get confused with 'No Such Channel' message when the call from the same channel is going.

Comment: You need subscribe for events. See links ABOVE for events.

Comment: Done it bro.. Thanks for the ideas.. +50 for following up.